# Setting Facebook PHP SDK access_token with setAccessToken()

Tags: php, ios, facebook, sdk

Currently I'm using the iOS api to get the access token and passing it to a webview as a cookie.  In the webview (because part of my app is iOS and the other part is html5 but I don't want to make the users log in twice) I'm grabbing the access token on the server side.

I'm setting the access token (using the Facebook PHP SDK) with the *setAccessToken()* function but immediately after, when I call *getUser()* I'm always getting 0 back.

I know that the SDK in general works as all of the code I am using is working for the normal "web" version.  Other people seem to have gotten this working so I'm hopeful that this is actually possible.  Been stuck on this for a while so would greatly appreciate any help / advice on getting this working soon!  Thanks!

Comment: really weird - so I just found out that a graph api call works, but getUser() (to get the id) still returns 0...

Answer (score 1):

In all my code, I now do not do "getUser" to find if the token is valid, but a "/me" call. getUser() often fails where "/me" works. So you're not alone with that finding. Then I get the userID from the /me call instead. All wrapped in try/catch, of course :)

Another tip: you say you're passing the session as a cookie - hopefully that's a cookie that you control? In my experience, don't mix "cookie" and "not cookie" mode - if you've manually handling with get/setAccessToken in one system, then turn off cookies everywehere (webview, php server, Javascript etc). After this, I've not had problems passing the tokens in what I'm trying to do.

Another thing to watch for, if you "setAccessToken" and it's invalid, the PHP SDK will clear out your session valiables if you have any. Not just PHP session variables, but all of them.

And finally, I've also had /me return logical values, but with things like FirstName as blank. Not ironed out why this happens, yet (and probably never will), but something else to program for when sharing tokens.

It's Facebook. Never meant to be easy {grin}.

Hope that helps.